# Using OR operator in re.search for multiple strings in python 3

Tags: regex, search, python-3.x

Sorry if this is already been asked, though i couldn't find it. Im trying to detect if a website uses wordpress. here is the sample code.

```
url = input("Please enter the URL")
if 'http://' in url:
    append = url
else:
    append = 'http://' + url
r = requests.get(append + "/robots.txt")
    response = r.text
if re.search(('/wp-includes/') | ('/wp-admin/'), response):
    print("{0} --> Its Wordpress ".format(append))
    sys.exit(0)
```

It says | operator cannot be used, in

```
if re.search(('/wp-includes/') | ('/wp-admin/'), response):
```

how can i search for multiple strings, with OR between them? i also tried using 'or' and tried this

```
if re.search('/wp-includes/' , '/wp-admin/'), response):
```

Thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The regex pattern is a single string.

```
'(foo|bar)'
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can i search for multiple strings, with OR between them?

Use an alternation operator `|`

```
if re.search(r'/wp-(?:admin|includes)/', response):
```